# how to retrieve header info using twitter API

Tags: node.js, twitter, meteor, coffeescript

i need to retrieve `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining` attribute from the header , i'm using 
the twitt Api for nodejs .
how can i access this attribute .
i need it to be able to sleep my loop to get all followers.

here's my coffee code :

```
loop
    r = Meteor.wrapAsync(twitter.get, twitter)('followers/list',{user_id:user?.services?.twitter?.id,cursor:cursor,cout:200})
    users.push.apply(users, r['users']);
    console.log r
    cursor=r['next_cursor']
    console.log cursor
    counter++
    if cursor is 0
      break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
twId = user?.services?.twitter?.id
getFollowers = Meteor.wrapAsync (cb) ->
  twitter.get 'followers/list', {user_id:twId,cursor:cursor,cout:200}, (err, data, response) ->
    cb(err, response)

r = getFollowers()
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback you pass to `Twitter.followers()` should look something like `function(error, data, response)`.  The `response` value that is returned is an object of type [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), which has various properties which will allow you to access the `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining` value (including `.headers` and `.rawHeaders`)

Comment: the problem isthat i'm using Meter.wrapAsync function :) , wait i'll update my question